# Using unelevated privileges from user when running shell script as root

Tags: bash, shell, root, privileges

I am creating an installation script for a small program I wrote and it needs to be ran as root in order to copy the executable to `/usr/bin/`, although, there is a part of script that must be ran as the non-root user.

I know it is bad practice to use sudo inside of a script, but that's the only way I can think of doing this without separating the files or asking for the username. Surely there must be another way.

If I knew the username of who was running the script as sudo I could use
`sudo -u username command`
inside the script for the non-root parts, but then how would I get the user's name without asking for it when running the script?

Comment: You should be able to use $SUDO_USER, so you can do `sudo -u $SUDO_USER command`

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted. I knew it'd be something simple like that, just didn't know it or how to search it

Answer (score 0):

As @Philippe commented, I just needed to

`sudo -u $SUDO_USER command`